# How could I remove one older folder with bash?

Tags: bash, sh

I have the following folders:

```
1435773881 Jul  1 21:04
1435774663 Jul  2 21:17
1435774856 Jul  3 21:20
1435775432 Jul  4 21:56
```

I need to remove older folder folder (`1435773881` in the case above) with bash script.

What command should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
ls -lt | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs rm -rf
```

- `ls -lt | tail -1` shows the last line after sorting the directories by date
- `awk '{print $NF}'` "prints" the last column (which is the directory name)
- `xargs rm -rf` deletes that directory

Comment: Instead of `ls -lrt | head -2 | tail -1`, couldn't you just do `ls -lt | tail -1`?

Comment: Is it possible to remove folder by providing absolute path?

Comment: I mean something like `find /path/to/base/dir -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;` But for my case?

Comment: @Erik recursive or not?

Comment: Yes I need to remove folder completely

Comment: @Erik `find` is a little bit difficult to solve it alone. `find` is very suitable to manipulate *files created at least(most) n days ago*, but not *the n oldest created files*. in you case, probably `-maxdepth 1` is needed. additionally, `ls` is a very bad starting point to manipulate file, since it won't print file names very honestly.

Comment: have a look at http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs to understand why `ls` is an error prone starting point

Comment: Your suggest `ls -lt | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs rm -rf` works for me fine but I need to make ls from another folder instead current.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to delete just the oldest file from the current folder:

```
rm -rf "$(ls -t | tail -1)";
```

And since you specifically asked for a way to provide an absolute path:

```
rm -rf "$1/$(ls -t "$1" | tail -1)";
```

Include the snipped above in a function...

```
function removeOldest
{
    rm -rf "$1/$(ls -t "$1" | tail -1)";
}
```

...or an executable named `removeOldest`

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf "$1/$(ls -t "$1" | tail -1)";
```

and call it like

```
removeOldest /path/to/the/directory
```

If you want to embed it in a script, just replace the both `$1` with the path directly.

Also note that if the specified directory contains no files at all, it is deleted itself.
If you want to prevent that, use

```
toBeDeleted="$(ls -t "$1" | tail -1)";
if [ ${#toBeDeleted} -gt 0 ] && [ -d "$1/$toBeDeleted" ]; then
    rm -rf "$1/$toBeDeleted";
fi;
```

Comment: It's seems I've found solution that works for me `ls -dt /path/to/base/* | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs rm -rf`